# Connect to WiFi network in WebApp on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, networking, flask, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am using a flask webserver on a Raspberry Pi, I'm using a wifi dongle. I'm trying to script so that it scans all the networks available and give them back in a webpage dropdownlist. Then when you click one it asks for a password and when I push a button 'Connect', it connects to the network.

Do you think that's possible?

I'm thinking of a method when you select a network and enter the password and press connect it adjusts the '/etc/network/interfaces' file and restarts the wlan0 interface (it doens't need to be really secure).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. You could do it manually with Scapy - http://www.devx.com/security/Article/34741. Or, if you're going a more simple route, try using the iwlist command.

Comment: Well I can already see my internet connections in a dropdown list with iwlist, you think its possible my example I gave to adjust the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: Yes... why wouldn't it be?